# I have a section of LINQ that I need to compare

Tags: linq

```
var myArray = ["A3|001", "A2|002", "A1|003"];
string myValue = "A2";
var No_NewList = myArray.Where(r => r.Contains(myValue.ToUpper())).ToList();
```

But this is not the result I want

I want the result to be `A2|002`

Comment: what is the result right now?

Comment: Do you want `myArray.Single(r => r.Contains(myValue.ToUpper()));`?

Comment: ["A3|001", "A2|002", "A1|003"] Now results

Comment: @WaiHaLee I want the result A2|002

Comment: The code above doesn't compile. Do you mean `var myArray = new[] { "A3|001", "A2|002", "A1|003" };`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var No_NewList = myArray
    .Where(s => myValue.Equals(s.Split('|')[0]))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```